# White lines appear on newsletter after using Slice Tool

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I created a flyer on Photoshop to send as a newsletter. So I used the slice tool to link certain parts of the flyer. When I sent a sample to my email, there are white lines around the images I linked and it's uneven.

Is there a way to prevent this? The reason I use Photoshop and Dreamweaver is because I have seen people do it and they did have any problems. 
I'm using MailChimp to create the newsletter. Here's a sample:

[image]

```
<html>
<head>

<title>centralvet</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (centralvet.psd) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="600" height="1032" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto 0 auto;">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="20">
            <img src="images/centralvet_01.jpg" width="600" height="30" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="30" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="4">
            <img src="images/centralvet_02.jpg" width="2" height="743" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="18"><a href="http://centralvet.cl/petshop/?s=pulgas&post_type=product"><img src="images/centralvet_03.jpg" width="595" height="136" alt=""></a></td>
        <td rowspan="9">
            <img src="images/centralvet_04.jpg" width="3" height="1001" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="136" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="18"><a href="http://centralvet.cl/petshop/?s=pulgas&post_type=product"><img src="images/centralvet_05.jpg" width="595" height="389" alt=""></a></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="389" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" rowspan="2"><a href="http://centralvet.cl/petshop/producto/comfortis-masticable-contra-pulgas-perros-de-18-1-a-27-2kg/"><img src="images/centralvet_06.jpg" width="207" height="218" alt=""></a></td>
        <td colspan="14">
            <img src="images/centralvet_07.jpg" width="388" height="8" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="8" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/centralvet_08.jpg" width="6" height="210" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="6"><a href="http://centralvet.cl/petshop/producto/advantage/"><img src="images/centralvet_09.jpg" width="131" height="210" alt=""></a></td>
        <td colspan="7">
            <img src="images/centralvet_10.jpg" width="251" height="210" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="210" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="17"><a href="http://centralvet.cl/petshop/"><img src="images/centralvet_11.jpg" width="466" height="113" alt=""></a></td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/centralvet_12.jpg" width="131" height="193" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="113" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="17">
            <img src="images/centralvet_13.jpg" width="466" height="80" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="80" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">
            <img src="images/centralvet_14.jpg" width="100" height="65" alt=""></td>
        <td><a href="https://twitter.com/centralvet"><img src="images/centralvet_15.jpg" width="52" height="52" alt=""></a></td>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img src="images/centralvet_16.jpg" width="6" height="65" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="2"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company-beta/3207290/?pathWildcard=3207290"><img src="images/centralvet_17.jpg" width="51" height="53" alt=""></a></td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">
            <img src="images/centralvet_18.jpg" width="8" height="65" alt=""></td>
        <td><a href="https://www.facebook.com/centralvet.cl"><img src="images/centralvet_19.jpg" width="50" height="52" alt=""></a></td>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img src="images/centralvet_20.jpg" width="5" height="65" alt=""></td>
        <td><a href="https://www.instagram.com/centralvet/"><img src="images/centralvet_21.jpg" width="52" height="52" alt=""></a></td>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img src="images/centralvet_22.jpg" width="4" height="65" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2"><a href="https://profiles.google.com/u/0/113315850160660587212/about"><img src="images/centralvet_23.jpg" width="53" height="52" alt=""></a></td>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img src="images/centralvet_24.jpg" width="4" height="65" alt=""></td>
        <td><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/centralvetchile/"><img src="images/centralvet_25.jpg" width="53" height="52" alt=""></a></td>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img src="images/centralvet_26.jpg" width="5" height="65" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/centralvet"><img src="images/centralvet_27.jpg" width="52" height="52" alt=""></a></td>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img src="images/centralvet_28.jpg" width="102" height="65" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="52" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/centralvet_29.jpg" width="52" height="13" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/centralvet_30.jpg" width="50" height="13" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/centralvet_31.jpg" width="52" height="13" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/centralvet_32.jpg" width="53" height="13" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/centralvet_33.jpg" width="53" height="13" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/centralvet_34.jpg" width="52" height="13" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/centralvet_35.jpg" width="51" height="12" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="12" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="2" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="98" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="52" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="6" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="51" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="6" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="2" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="50" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="5" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="52" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="4" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="18" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="35" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="4" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="53" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="5" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="23" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="29" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="102" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="3" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve this question.  Namely, include a [mcve] on the question itself as external links can become unreachable for a number of reasons (making the question impossible to answer)

Comment: Without the actual code, have a look at the padding/spacing between `div` elements or (*shudders*) `table` and its cells (`td`) elements - if there is any, you can reduce them to zero to eliminate the white lines between splices

Comment: What happens if you remove all the `spacer.gif` images? that seems to be the culprit right there